# How to add a comment using service api when uuid_service module is enabled

Tags: services, entities

How to add a comment when UUID and services are enabled
The url which we tried is :

http://localhost/api/comment/uuid_of_new_comment (PUT request)
with json raw data:

```
{
    "comment": {
        "uuid":"uuid_of_forum ",
        "subject": "testing"
    },
    "uuid":"uuid_of_new_comment ",
    "type":"comment"
}
```

I know that it is not correct. But was not able to find a proper documentation for this any where. So trying some random things !!!

It will be highly helpful if some one can suggest where to find proper documentation for uuid with services .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We got it working finally:

URL Used : https://localhost/api/comment/0b1dd306-bbcb-410c-b991-319a3ca189c3
METHOD: PUT
JSON:

```
{
    "nid": "2583",
    "name": "dsad",
    "subject": "sda",
    "language": "und",
    "node_type": "comment_node_forum",
    "date": "now",
    "status": 0,
    "is_anonymous": true,
    "op": "edit",
    "comment_body": {
        "und": [
            {
                "value": "jhkjh"
            }
        ]
    },
    "uuid": "0b1dd306-bbcb-410c-b991-319a3ca189c3"
}
```

And to allow users other than administers to add comment the patch in the following issue has to be applied:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2236229

Comment: If this is the correct answer you can check it as correct, this will help other users ;-)

Answer (score 1):

First, when creating a comment you must use *POST*. Here's an example:

**POST**: `?q=[my_endpoint]/comment.json`

```
{
  "subject":"Testing...",
  "comment_body":{"und":[{"value":"Hello world..."}]},
  "nid":"123"
}
```

Secondly, from my understanding the *uuid* will automatically be generated server side, so you should not need to send it up to Drupal. And lastly, you use the *PUT* http method to update a comment, and in that case you can send along similar JSON, but include the cid value (e.g. 456) and exclude the nid value in the JSON object, and change the URL path to `?q=[my_endpoint]/comment/456.json`

```
{
  "subject":"Updating...",
  "comment_body":{"und":[{"value":"Hello world again..."}]},
  "cid":"456"
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. But when we use uuid with services POST wont work. We have to use PUT. We got it working. The solution is posted below.